# Check for Bakcspace or Delete Key

Tags: javascript, textarea, keycode, onkeydown

I'm playing with a textarea and trying to make it so the user cannot exceed maxLength unless the key pressed is a backspace or delete key. The problem is my keyCode conditional is always coming out to true. Why is that?

```
var maxLength = 500;
window.onload = init;                // this seems to be a problem
commentBox.onkeydown = checkLength;

function checkLength(e)
{
    var evt = e || window.event;

    if(countText() < maxLength) //countText successfully returns number of nonwhitespace text.
        return true;
    else if(evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.keycode == 8)  // 46 = delete, 8 = backspace.
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E7Ve/3/) to help better understand. The delete key works in JSFiddle but not locally for some reason or another. Delete on the otherhand still does not work.

Comment: Don't do that. You only care that the right number of characters are entered when the user submits the data, before then it's of no interest to you. Just tell them whether they're over the limit or not and let the user sort it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it finally....

You are using **evt.keycode** which is a small typo error

```
 else if(evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.keyCode == 8)  // 46 = delete, 8 = backspace.
```

Cheers